# how to reload page only first time without infinite loop Jquery

Tags: jquery, caching, reload

i want reload the page with `location.reload(true)` beacuase every time i must press ctrl + f5 to refresh the cache.
My problem is that if I try to put this function inside an onload i get an infinite loop beacuase it trigger itself

Comment: You could use a flag in localStorage to prevent successive reloads. However I'd suggest that a better approach would be to fix the caching problem which requires the reload in the first instance.

Comment: so, exist a way to fix the caching problem without this function?

Comment: If this is just for debugging, then Chrome has an option in DevTools (F12) / Settings (cog on right) / Networking / Disable cache (while DevTools is open).   If this is for live, then you probably want a method to not cache items - either add a datestamp on your requests (so they skip cache) or provide proper caching server-side.

Comment: oh, ok interesting, thanks very much for the response